# Given $y=e^{2x}(\cosh x + \sinh x).$ Show that the second derivative is $9y$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given $y=e^{2x}(\cosh x + \sinh x)$. Show that the second derivative is $9y$. The answer I get is $e^x + 6e^{3x}$. I used the product rule to solve it. But how can the second derivative be $9y$? How can I get that answer? Can anyone explain to me ?

Comment: Can you [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3999113/edit) your question to show us your work?

Comment: you should get the first derivative as $3y$. Did you get that? If yes, then it is obvious why the second derivative will be $9y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you simplify the original expression using the definitions
$$\cosh x =\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2} \quad \sinh x =\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$$

you'll see that the second factor is simply $e^x$. Then
$$y(x)=e^{2x}\cdot e^x=e^{3x}$$
from which it follows
$$y''(x)=9e^{3x}=9y(x)$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$\cosh x+\sinh x=\cdots=e^x$

Now  if $y=e^{mx},$

$ y_1=me^{mx},$

$y_2=?$

More generally if $$y=e^{mx}(a\cosh x+b\sinh x)$$

using [General Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) or by repeated differentiation

$$y_2=m^2e^{mx}(a\cosh x+b\sinh x)+\binom21me^{mx}(a\sinh x+b\cosh x)+e^{mx}(a\cosh x+b\sinh x)$$

If $a=b$

$$y_2$$
$$=am^2e^{mx}(\cosh x+\sinh x)+\binom21me^{mx}(\sinh x+\cosh x)+e^{mx}(\cosh x+\sinh x)$$

$$=(m+1)^2y$$

Answer (score 2):

$$y=e^{2x}(\text{cosh} x+ \text{sinh} x)=e^{3x} \implies y'=3 e^{3x}, y''= 9 e^{3x}=9y.$$

Answer (score 0):

$y(x)=\exp(2x) (\cosh(x)+\sinh(x))$, so by using the product rule and the fact that $\cosh'=\sinh$, $\sinh'=\cosh$, we get $$y'(x)=\exp(2x) (\cosh(x)+\sinh(x)) + 2 \exp(2x) (\cosh(x)+\sinh(x))=3y(x).$$

Because $y'(x)=3y(x)$, we get $y''(x)=(y'(x))'=3y'(x)=9y(x)$.